# Shutting off broiler pilot completely

Tags: gas, stove

I have a 1972 Kenmore,  the broiler is at the top of the inside of stove.  Can I completely shut off the pilot light to the broiler?  It has a screw that adjusts they flame.

Comment: Can you add a model number of the stove?

Comment: Model No 143-6106801-171

Answer (score -1):

You can just blow out the pilot light and once it cools down (a few minutes at worst), the pilot light assembly will shut off the gas. A pilot light for a stove has a safety device called a thermocouple that is tied to a valve as a safety precaution against accidentally losing the pilot flame.

Relighting it will not be simple however. When you want to re-light it, you have to hold a reset button down while applying a flame to that device long enough to get it to open the valve again. That is not something for the faint of heart and is not something you want to do every time you want to use the oven...

Here's a video of the typical procedure (yours may vary slightly) if you want to assess your desire to go down this road.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glX70JM-aFY

Comment: I’m talking about the broiler pilot light which is located at the top of the stove, it blows out when you start the oven or close the door too hard.  There is a gas smell when the broiler pilot goes out.  It has a screw adjustment for the flame, can you shut off the gas by that screw?

Comment: Beware of assuming advanced safety features on old gas appliances. They are not there...